# Prevent folder from being picked up

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url

So I have a site, and I'm trying to achieve URLs like Twitter. Here's my code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1
```

The issue with this is I have pages such as `/signup` and `/forgot`, and when I go to them they get picked up as users. So what I did was put each page I didn't want htaccess to pick up in a folder like `signup`, and that contained `index.php` for the signup page. But htaccess still counts it as a username. So my question is how can I fix this? I want to "prevent" certain links (folders) from being counted as a user.

I know

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

Works for files, but is there one for folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^(signup|forgot)($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the poorly-written rules that were preventing `!-f` from working...

Comment: OP wanted a way to prevent folders from being applied. And I'd assume it works. But your answer gives more details which is great. @zx81

Answer (score 1):

**`!-f` already does what you want. The problem was that you had two rules—conditions apply to a single rule.**

Therefore, the second rule was getting applied even for folders that exist.

This combines the rule into one single rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1
```

- If the filename is an existing folder or file, `!-f` or `!-d` conditions will fail and the rule will not apply. Existing folders like `signup` will not be rewritten.
- The `/?` in the rule makes the `/` optional, combining both cases.
- The `\w` can match letters, digits and underscores